# the drop down needs to be visible in the grid load in extjs 4/5

Tags: extjs5

in this pic this combo visible after selected,
but i want to visible when this grid load.
please advise me ?

{

```
            header: "Consequence",
            dataIndex: 'consequence',
            width: 100,
            sortable: false
            editor: {

                xtype: 'combo',
                store: 'ConsequenceMatrix',
                model: 'ConsequenceMatrix',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'name',
                typeAhead: false,
                minChars: 0,
                scope: this,
                listeners: {
                    select: function (combo, records) {
                        this.setValue(records[0].get('name'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what Widget Columns are for. Here's [an example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/a4v) I happened to prepare this morning.

Widget columns are a new feature in ExtJS 5.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert Watkins and i resolved my problem that is given by you :)